# How to Optimize in python with backpropagation keras

Tags: python, keras, optimization, backpropagation

I am trying to optimize a function but internally it takes many calculations and with scypy the results are very mediocre.

example :

```
def function(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 ... xn):
           ......
           ......
           ......
           ......
           return Y
```

the objective is to find the most optimal parameters **x1,x2,x3,...xn**  to maximize **Y**. I would like to know if it is possible to optimize the function with some keras algorithm or something like that

Comment: Please tell all about your function. Is it differentiable? Convex? Smooth? Quick to calculate?

Comment: since it is a function to calculate the steam production in a boiler, it is definitely not differentiable, it has many conditions and restrictions

Comment: the keras optimizer depends on the function to be differentialble, so this is not going to help you much